# Use different fonts for different languages in geany or other text editor?

Tags: editor, geany

In Geany, I want to use a font (like "Times New Roman") for latex, and use other font (like "Courier") for Python. How to do it?

If there's no way to do it in Geany, is it possible to do it in other text editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something close can be done with Geany *if* you're not planning to use the different languages within one instance of Geany at the same time. The idea is to start Geany using a different configuration directory for each different language.

Say you're default font in Geany is "Courier", so it's already good for Python. For a different language, e.g. LaTeX, copy the default configuration directory located at `~/.config/geany/` to a new location such as `~/.config/geany_latex`. Start Geany with the command `geany -c ~/.config/geany_latex` and change the font to "Times New Roman". Then start Geany with `geany` or `geany -c ~/.config/geany_latex` to work on Python or LaTeX, respectively. Repeat for other languages as desired. Finally, set up shortcuts in your DE's GUI for each of the different languages to avoid having to remember the particular geany startup command for each.

Comment: what is purpose of `c` in `geany -c ~/.config/geany_latex`?

Comment: @ydhhat, it's a command line option for specifying a configuration directory to use as an alternate to the default configuration directory. For info on Geany's command line options, see https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#command-line-options.